# CURL Cookies successfully sent via Windows Command Prompt fail via Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, curl

If I send the below two commands within a Windows Command Prompt

Command 1:

> curl -d userId="my.name" -d password="my.password"
>   https://localhost:443/test/login -X POST -c "cookies.txt" -w
>   "%{response_code}" -k

Command 2:

> curl -F file1=@"C:\test.zip" https://localhost:443/test/upload -b
>   "cookies.txt" -w "%{response_code}" -k

The cookies are received in the second call.

If I put the same two commands in a Windows batch file, the cookies are not received in the second call. Why?

**Update:**

The problem seems to be related to the passing of the cookie in the second call within the batch file. CURL's verbose output for the second call in Command Prompt (2nd command only, outside batch file) is:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=localhost
*  start date: May 31 14:47:57 2017 GMT
*  expire date: May 31 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  issuer: CN=localhost
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x1c3ff9650f0)
> POST /test/upload HTTP/2
> Host: localhost:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: .AspNetCore.Password=VfDJ8DTHwtekoe5CixP71DROzvv-mAa0MfVBtNW71ESzGLMJ6txx48wVZU_w6nBczSP681tzYTUHLsgGVuvo2lx6pwTO-WJhpDvUcSxsUWKNurEqgZBRBo0RxLK4ubHCcncNnAbVCsc_McoKcEHFqy-cFvztqEDtNPlG7UTmI2685tfzM_W7csgUIOL9nfbo3T4cCytJXBfqCSrHRBkNN_wDD6QhDOpuiBKdy5cVhN4pXA2zh4WyCtOmrVHrJDwDDTdJEZMj7j59Y1AGT1diV8QivU2DuMcwbMrT7y3TmFRwhw5j30wukAV95MYw4357_87SX4XY9WwAJdncL0fMJ3OznVTVC9rUI3Tvi8M6KKfV3Lkb
> Content-Length: 735
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------8ecfb7321f78c8b5
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 202
< cache-control: no-cache
< pragma: no-cache
< expires: -1
< server: Kestrel
* Replaced cookie .AspNetCore.Password="" for domain localhost, path /test, expire 1
< set-cookie: .AspNetCore.Password=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/test
< x-sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUHJvamVjdHNcVmV0Q29tcGFzc1xjb2RlXGFzcFxWZXRDb21wYXNzLlVJXHNyY1xWZXRDb21wYXNzLlVJXGFwaVxkYXRhdXBsb2FkXHVwbG9hZA==?=
< x-powered-by: ASP.NET
< date: Wed, 14 Jun 2017 13:46:28 GMT
< content-length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
202
```

Inside the batch file (2nd command only, exact same command) the verbose output is:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: ÔÇôb/
* Failed to convert ÔÇôb to ACE;
* Could not resolve host: ÔÇôb
* Closing connection 0
000curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ÔÇôb
* Rebuilt URL to: cookies.txt/
*   Trying 81.200.64.50...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to cookies.txt (81.200.64.50) port 80 (#1)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: cookies.txt
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 735
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------5fb5c68be6042795
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #1 to host cookies.txt left intact
000curl: (52) Empty reply from server
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 443 (#2)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=localhost
*  start date: May 31 14:47:57 2017 GMT
*  expire date: May 31 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  issuer: CN=localhost
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x1fda6c350f0)
> POST /test/upload HTTP/2
> Host: localhost:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 735
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------bf4df70798c79cba
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 502
< cache-control: private
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< x-sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUHJvamVjdHNcVmV0Q29tcGFzc1xjb2RlXGFzcFxWZXRDb21wYXNzLlVJXHNyY1xWZXRDb21wYXNzLlVJXGFwaVxkYXRhdXBsb2FkXHVwbG9hZA==?=
< x-powered-by: ASP.NET
< date: Wed, 14 Jun 2017 13:52:09 GMT
< content-length: 4963
* Connection #2 to host localhost left intact
502
```

As soon as I remove `-b "cookies.txt"` the `Rebuilt URL to: ÔÇôb/` output goes away.

Comment: Try to double all `%` percent signs. `... -w "%%{response_code}"`

Comment: thanks @jeb. Already doing that. CURL in the batch file does something strange as soon as `-b cookies.txt` is added to the second call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the encoding of the batch file. Very embarrassing that I didn't check this before. I didn't realise the file wasn't ANSI encoded. There was a UTF-8 character that looked like a hyphen. After converting to ANSI encoding, the character showed itself.